What does "it breaks" refer to?
One evening, Oppenheimer and his team reach a ranch by horse. They stop at
one point and dismount:

Oppenheimer: This'll do. It'll break before dawn. Air cools overnight, just
before dawn, it breaks.

Actually, in the context, Oppenheimer didn’t particularly mention any specific
object to understand what he meant by ‘it breaks’
What does "it breaks" refer to?

There's a wind storm going on, so Oppenheimer is referring to the wind.
The original screenplay has slightly different wording which clarifies.

It’ll break before dawn. The air cools overnight. Just before dawn, the storm dies.

